# i lost my ms apps when trying to fix the ms store?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-store

[image is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/licB0.png)

as you can see i have lost the icon for ms apps and can't open them because i tried a command in windows PowerShell (Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"} ) that should have fixed ms store not installing apps, and im using windows 10.

Comment: What problem were you originally having? What command did you run that "should have" fixed it?

Comment: i had a problem that said, couldn't install we will retry shortly , the command i used was:                                                                                                                                                           Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

Comment: @Mokubai can you help me ?